# ICommand.Execute(object parameter) on RoutedCommand

Tags: wpf

If I execute the explicitly implemented

```
ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
```

method on a RoutedCommand , the command is executed as expected. There must be logic within the RoutedCommand to resolve the position from where the command was executed. Maybe it’s done through StackTrace? Probably it's the same as calling RoutedCommand.Execute(parameter,null).

Does someone know more about this topic (logic, reliability) or has a good link to share ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the implementation using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), it looks like it uses [Keyboard.FocusedElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.focusedelement.aspx) to determine the target.

```
void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
{
    this.Execute(parameter, FilterInputElement(Keyboard.FocusedElement));
}
```